# Trigger Workflow from Button Click

Tags: apex, custom-button, workflowoutboundmessage

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

When a user is viewing or editing an opportunity they should have an "Export" button available to them. When they click this button a workflow is triggered which then sends out an outbound message.

From what I've found so far it sounds like there is no built-in way to do this. The best recommendation I've come across is to create a custom button and write some Apex to call the workflow... somehow.

I haven't been able to find any examples to go along with the recommendations I've come across. I would really appreciate any suggestions or other ways to accomplish what I need to do along with a small code sample.

I've been doing Salesforce development for less than a week and I've been reading as much documentation as possible. Needless to say I am very new at this.

Comment: I think there's an issue with terminology. This sounds like a task or "activity". Workflow only happens when a record has been inserted, updated or deleted. I highly recommend you spend time going through the [Force.com workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook.meta/workbook/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a javascript button that updates a field on the opportunity, and then have your workflow fire off that field.  Let's assume you put a hidden checkbox on the opportunity called Hidden_Checkbox__c

Your button would look something like

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/31.0/connection.js")} 

var myquery = "SELECT Id, Name, Hidden_Checkbox__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = '{!Opportunity.Id}' limit 1"; 

result = sforce.connection.query(myquery); 
records = result.getArray("records"); 

var myOpp = records[0]; 
var updateOpp = new Array(); 

myOpp.Hidden_Checkbox__c = true; 
updateOpp.push(myOpp); 

result = sforce.connection.update(updateOpp); 

if(result[0].getBoolean("success")){ 
    window.location = "/" + "{!Opportunity.Id}"; 
}else{ 
    alert('Could not Export : '+result); 
}
```

Then you just set up your Workflow to fire off the checkbox being set to true.  (you might also want to set it to false as a field update as well)

Comment: I don't want to sound like I'm criticizing your answer because it looks like it will definitely do what I need. However, do you think there's a more elegant way to handle this type of thing in SF? Are most solutions to "non-standard" SF problems going to require something hacky?