# Call Process from Visualforce Page Button

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, process-builder

Does anyone know if it is possible to call a Process from a Visualforce page button?  My situation is that I have a custom object with a Master-Detail relationship to the Opportunity object.  When the user creates a record of the custom object, I want to have a button that would create an associated Case when clicked.  In the past, I have done this via a URL hack, but I would like to use something more scalable like a Process but I'm not sure how to get the button to do this.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: and why not have the VF page button do DML in the controller such that the process' triggering condition executes?

Comment: My page is using a standard controller so I do not have a custom controller to be used.

Comment: ok, then change the custom button to use SFDC Javascript/Ajax and update the object that way

Comment: Thanks @crop1645, but I don't know JavaScript very well.

Comment: see http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/70837/2602 for an example

Answer (score 3):

If you're wanting to do it that way, you really should just go and do it in Visual Flow.  You can have your Visual Flow do that, and you don't even need a Process Builder!

Check out this on writing your VFP to house the Flow:
http://salesforcesidekick.com/2015/05/25/how-to-put-your-flow-in-a-visualforce-page/

And this is a great example of this in action, except that its using a URL button instead of VFP, but combine them together and you'll have what you asked for:
http://salesforcesidekick.com/2015/06/25/assign-to-me-button/

Comment: Thanks @David.  I'll take a look and see if I can make it work for me.